# Querying a Array with list of anonymous Object

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, linq, reflection

In my application I have an  Array of Objects,
The type of all objects will be always same but unknown but I need to update one property of object of array based on some condition

I tried to implement the same like below using reflection

```
  Public Shared Sub FilterobjectArray(ByVal obj As Object())
     
            Dim r = obj.Where(Function(x) CStr(x.[GetType]().GetProperty("Id")?.GetValue(x)) = "2")

            For Each item In r
                Dim propertyInfo As PropertyInfo = item.[GetType]().GetProperty("CompanyName")
                propertyInfo.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType("MyCompany", propertyInfo.PropertyType), Nothing)
            Next           
    End Sub
```

Problem
I think the Lambda  expression for filtering the array is wrong as it throws "Object reference not set " in x

My sample implementation

Company Entity

```
Public Class Company
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property CompanyName As String
End Class
```

Implementation

```
    Dim comp(2) As Object
    Dim comp1 = New Company With {.Id = 1, .CompanyName = "Comp1"}
    Dim comp2 = New Company With {.Id = 2, .CompanyName = "Comp2"}
    comp(0) = comp1
    comp(1) = comp2
    FilterobjectArray(comp)
```

Can Someone Suggest What is wrong ,C# answers or syntax is also welcome

NB: error appears after first iteration in for loop
i.e. after first  "propertyInfo.SetValue" completes and next iteration start

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection? Can't you simply use an interface instead?

Comment: Because we don't know the type of object , so to filter based on a property value we used reflection

Comment: You're not adding any of the items to the array. The array has three `Nothing` values when you pass it to `FilterobjectArray`.

Comment: I've used the [Telerik Code converter](https://converter.telerik.com/) to convert your VB code to C# and it does translate it to an array of Object with 3 slots. And none of them are set.

Comment: @Enigmativity  Thanks .. But it was not the issue, I had already done the array fill in actual code but forgot to add it in SO. Sorry , I had updated the question the error message is also added

Comment: @SreenathGanga I'll repeat Peter's comment. Why don't you use an interface? If you know the name of the property, you know enough about the type already. You don't need reflection. At best, you need to filter for objects that don't implement the interface with, eg `OfType<>()`

Comment: In fact, why use an `Object` array instead of a List<T> ? It's easier to fix a bad design that trying to fix the problems it creates

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos we are trying to write an integrator to an existing 3rd party application .. so have no option

Comment: Do all the objects actually have that property? Otherwise `GetProperty` returns null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code you need:

```
Sub Main
    Dim comp(1) As Object
    comp(0) = New Company With {.Id = 1, .CompanyName = "Comp1"}
    comp(1) = New Company With {.Id = 2, .CompanyName = "Comp2"}

    FilterobjectArray(comp)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub FilterobjectArray(ByVal obj As Object())
    Dim r = obj.Where(Function(x) CStr(x.[GetType]().GetProperty("Id")?.GetValue(x)) = "2")
    For Each item As Object In r
        Dim propertyInfo As PropertyInfo = item.[GetType]().GetProperty("CompanyName")
        propertyInfo.SetValue(item, Nothing)
    Next
End Sub
```

You need to add the elements to the array first. Most everything else was good, I just simplified the `SetValue` call.

Comment: Thanks .. But it was not the issue, I had already done the array fill in actual code but forgot to add it in SO. Sorry , I had updated the question the error message is also added

Comment: The error shows up after first    "propertyInfo.SetValue(item, Nothing) "

Comment: Thank..now i got your point  after reading  peter and caius

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in C# where you declare the size of an array, when you declare an array in VB you specify the last valid index. This means an array declared as `object(2)` has 3 slots - 0 (arrays start from 0), 1 and 2. You've put 2 objects so the third slot is null.

You then ForEach which hits the third null slot, but there is a twist:

The error window is telling you x is nothing, x is the variable used in the LINQ query. The LINQ query does not run on the line where you say `Where`, it runs as soon as you use the variable r in the ForEach.. So it might look like it's the first item that is causing the error because the ForEach is exploding, but it's not: it's the fact that the LINQ execution (that will hit the error on the third slot) is delayed until you enumerate the results of the LINQ query. If you add a `.ToList()` call onto the end of your Where, then the code will crash before your ForEach..

Add another object to your array in index 2, reduce the array to an `object(1)` or provide some protection against x being Nothing if your system will encounter null objects naturally at run time